# two classes, same property name, different type -> gets overridden

Tags: ios, xcode, class, overriding, instance-variables

I have the following setup: Two classes, one imports the other, both have a property that happens to have the same name but a different type.

When I try to access the someColor property in ClazzB, I get an error:

```
[[[ClazzB sharedInstance] someColor] CGColor]
```

Error:
No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'CGColor'

The error clearly suggest that it takes the property from ClazzA, the question is why? Is there some weird name overridden going on?

Here the setup:

```
@interface ClazzA : NSObject {
   @private
   NSString* _someColor;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* someColor;
```

ClazzB imports ClazzA and has a property with the same name but with a different type.

```
#import "ClazzA.h"

@interface ClazzB : NSObject {
    UIColor* _someColor;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* someColor;
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show declaration of your "sharedInstance" method?

Comment: It's a singleton.

`+ (id)sharedInstance { static ClazzB *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}`

Comment: As I mentioned below. Don't use `id` as a return type for such methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above I asked you for a sharing declaration of your `sharedInstance` method but I suspect it is

```
+ (id)sharedInstance;
```

That's a reason of a problem. In this case compiler doesn't know what exact type you will get there and just chooses first matched selector for `someColor` which returns `NSString *`.

I'd recommend to change your `sharedInstance` methods declaration to

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
```

or

```
+ (ClazzA *)sharedInstance;
+ (ClazzB *)sharedInstance;
```

I'd prefer `instancetype` way.